# MS clarity can be integrated in AMP pages?

Tags: javascript, analytics, amp-html, ms-clarity

I am currently working with website made using AMP.I want to integrate with MS clarity on this page but not able to find any way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in Clarity. We don’t support AMP right now, we will consider this feedback and add it our backlog.